# Serialization missing record delimiter in ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, serialization, coldfusion, ascii, coldfusion-11

I am using `0x1E`( record separator ascii value: 30 ) as delimiter in my sql queries and facing issue while trying to serialize the query result or invoking the method as web services.

The issue is that the record separator character is missing from the JSON returned.

I also tried escaping all the hidden characters using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()` but none found.

When I dump the query result then I can see the character there but not on outputing/dumping the serialized result.

Following are the screenshots:

**Query Dump:**

[image]

**Serialization dump:**

[image]

**Edit:**

After trying on different versions found that the same is not working on TryCF with [`CF10`](https://trycf.com/gist/1eaace0e218eecf6d9ec832709f7e5c0/acf?theme=monokai) but working for [`CF11`](https://trycf.com/gist/e4660cfd869f7fa5890e2612b17c44ab/acf11?theme=monokai). Is that a bug that was fixed in recent patches as it is not working on CF 11,0,06,295053?

Any suggestions!

Comment: Given that chr(30) is a non printing character, looks might be deceiving.  You might want to verify the problem by replacing it with a more visible string when you eyeball it.

Comment: @DanBracuk It should be unicoded while serializing. Isn't it? And printable character is working fine. Do you have any suggestion for the delimiter I should use?

Comment: Yes, there is a related bug.  https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-3561029 . Why a delimiter as opposed to returning say an array of elements?

Comment: ... or did you mean the data itself contains chr(30)?

Comment: @Ageax No, I am changing the default delimiter(,) to chr(30)

Comment: @Beginner - Not sure I follow ... default delimiter of what - CFML function, MySQL, ... ? Can you show an example?

Comment: @Ageax Default for group_concat() in mysql and then using the with CF list functions.

Comment: @Beginner - I don't know if there is a 100% "safe" delimiter... Why not use arrays once the data gets to CF? Split the mysql list on chr(30).

Comment: [`encodeForJavaScript`](https://cfdocs.org/encodeforjavascript) might work, but seems like `serializeJSON` will end up double escaping the string. This [TryCF gist](https://trycf.com/gist/bfc3716ad0177d53c360288feeb23e09/acf?theme=monokai) dose show the character is lost in CF10. Like Ageax is suggesting, converting the list to an array may be the best approach.